# selecting a doc right after being created in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

in the function newNote i tried to select in the screen the newNote when is created but wont work, it kept giving me a undefined in selectNote call in the end

```
const newNote = async (title) => {
const note = {
title: title,
body: '',
timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
};
const dbRef = collection(db, 'notes');

    const newFromDB = await addDoc(dbRef, note);
    const newID = newFromDB.id;
    const updatedNotes = [...notes, note];
    setNotes(updatedNotes);

    const newNoteIndex = updatedNotes.findIndex((_note) => _note.id === newID);
   
    selectNote(updatedNotes[newNoteIndex], newNoteIndex);

};
```

i wanted that the recently created note show up in the screen by the selectNote function